# OpenTSDB: Zookeeper Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

I am doing installation of opentsdb for the first time on Ubuntu. I am following these documentations for installation:
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html#id1
[http://opentsdb.net/setup-hbase.html](http://opentsdb.net/setup-hbase.)

I am getting following error on executing the command

Abharthan/opentsdb$ env COMPRESSION=NONE HBASE_HOME=/home/administrator/Abharthan/hbase-0.98.13-hadoop1
 ./src/create_table.sh

after installing OpenTSDB:
I have already installed hbase, gnuplot, JDK etc.

There were some errors regarding:

1. Can't get connection to zookeeper

   Some answers to this suggest:
   It seems like your zookeeper is down/not configured on poort 2181
   you can start by checking the zoo.cfg file where you installed zookeepr

But, I didn't installed zookeeper explicitly, it was supposed to be installed by the opentsdb/hbase itself. Where can I find this file to make this change.

2. Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform
3. SLF4J: Classpath contains multiple SLF4J building

   > HBase Shell; enter 'help' for list of
   >   supported commands. Type "exit" to leave the HBase Shell
   >   Version 0.98.13-hadoop1, r8f54f8daf8cf4d1a629f8ed62363be29141c1b6e,
   >   Wed Jun 10 22:18:15 PDT 2015
   >
   > create 'tsdb-uid',   {NAME => 'id', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER
   >   => 'ROW'},   {NAME => 'name', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW'} SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J:
   >   Found binding in
   >   [jar:file:/home/administrator/Abharthan/hbase-0.98.13-hadoop1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   >   SLF4J: Found binding in
   >   [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   >   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
   >   explanation. 2015-07-03 08:44:12,270 ERROR [main]
   >   zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4
   >   attempts 2015-07-03 08:44:12,273 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil:
   >   hconnection-0x225875070x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
   >   Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
   >   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:
   >   KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid   at
   >   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
   >     at
   >   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
   >     at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)   at
   >   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
   >     at
   >   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:481)
   >     at
   >   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
   >     at
   >   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
   >     at
   >   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:909)
   >     at
   >   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(HConnectionManager.java:703)
   >     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
   >   Method)   at
   >   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   >     at
   >   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   >     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
   >     at
   >   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:459)
   >   . . .

I am able to start the hbase server as:

> ```
> Abharthan/hbase-0.98.13-hadoop1$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh 
> starting master, logging to /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-1.0.1.1/logs/hbaseIdeaCentre-Q190.out
> ```

Running following command

> Abharthan/opentsdb$ ./build/tsdb tsd --port=4242 --staticroot=build/staticroot --cachedir="$tsdtemp"

gives this result:

> 2015-07-03 09:49:19,220 INFO  [main] TSDMain: Starting. 2015-07-03
>   09:49:19,231 INFO  [main] TSDMain: net.opentsdb 2.1.0 built at
>   revision 45e575a (MINT) 2015-07-03 09:49:19,232 INFO  [main] TSDMain:
>   Built on 2015/06/30 21:00:14 +0000 by
>   IdeaCentre-Q190:/home/administrator/Abharthan/opentsdb/build
>   2015-07-03 09:49:19,255 INFO  [main] Config: No configuration found,
>   will use defaults Missing cache directory

Can someone suggest what is the problem.

Also, it says I can open it in browser as localhost:4242, but where to mention the port the service use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1 (The failing zookeeper) is the problem. We have a running openTSDB and often see errors 2 and 3; they are not serious.

You will need to track down the cause of zookeepers failure; look for the zookeeper log files.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure your hadoop and hbase have already started before create opentsdb table, and it will be fine.